# Direct2D fallback to GDI in XP

Tags: windows-xp, gdi+, direct2d

I'd like to use Direct2D for my .Net application using the Windows Code pack. Since some of my users are using XP, I need to provide a GDI+ fallback. I wonder how people usually do this kind of fallback.

Do they abstract/interface all the necessary graphics feature into some custom generic library? If so, is there any open-source library for direct2d/GDI?

Thanks,
Gil.

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it is by having two completely seperate classes (both derived from an `IRenderer` interface). On load, I determine the operating system version using Window's `GetVersionEx` function. If `dwMajorVersion >= 6`, then I load the Direct2D class; otherwise it falls back to GDI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to re-program it in Direct3D if you want it to run as fast.